# Recycler view is not scroling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a Recycler View inside a Viewpager that is inside a NestedScroll View

My layout is as follows

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
    <AppBarLayout>
        <CollapsingToolbarLayout>
            <Toolbar>
            </Toolbar>
        </CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </AppBarLayout>
    <NestedScrollView>
        <ViewPager>
            <RecyclerView>
            </RecyclerView>
        </ViewPager>
    </NestedScrollView>
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

I have more contents inside the RecyclerView but the view is showing items items till the AppBarLayout is being scrolled.

How to make the recycler view scroll complete list?

Below are the screenshots of the View
[image]
[image]

Edit:
Here is the XML

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="128dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="128dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="128dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="32dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/amaranth"
                    android:text="@string/app_name" />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/search_et"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="59dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
                    android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
                    android:hint="Search"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:imeOptions="actionGo"
                    android:padding="10dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    app:layout_anchor="@id/nested_scroll_view"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
    android:id="@+id/card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:cardElevation="1dp"
    app:cardMaxElevation="3dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout

        android:id="@+id/tablayout"
        style="@style/MyCustomTabTextAppearance"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/whiteColor"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/tabBackgroundColor"
        app:tabMode="fixed">

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Java Code
    searchResultsRecyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.search_recycler_view);
        searchResultsRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        searchResultsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

```
    searchEditText = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.search_et);
    searchEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> asyncTask;
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            if (asyncTask == null) {
                asyncTask = new SearchAsyncTask(editable.toString()).execute();
            } else {
                asyncTask.cancel(true);
                asyncTask = new SearchAsyncTask(editable.toString()).execute();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please post your full XML file and your JAVA code.

Comment: Did you put your recycler view in a fragment? And then you showed that rv from fragment in viewpager.. Right??????

Comment: Yes! exactly that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line before setAdapter to RecylerView 
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);

Answer (score 0):

use recyclerview height wrap_content

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your recycler view xml

android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"